# How to limit to upload mulpltiple files using ng-file-upload in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need one help.I need keep limit of selecting files using `ng-file-upload` in Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<input
  type="file"
  class="filestyle form-control"
  data-size="lg"
  name="bannerimage"
  id="bannerimage"
  ng-model="file"
  ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
  accept="image/*"
  ngf-max-size="2MB"
  ngf-min-height="100"
  ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}"
  custom-on-change="uploadFile"
  required="required"
  ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);"
  ngf-multiple="true"
>
```

Here i have multiple file selecting scenario but i need user can only select maximum 5 files after that it can not select any file.Please help me.

Comment: Upgrade to 11.1.0 and use `ngf-max-files="10"`

Answer (score 0):

What about the attribute ngf-select-disabled

With a condition like "myFiles.length > 5" ?

You could add ngf-drop-disabled too if te user can use drag and drop.

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload